# Apache Nifi view and download functions not working

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm in the process of learning Nifi and was following a video guide where it shows retrieving a file using the GetFile processor. As part of the video, it was demonstrated that you could view the contents of a file going through the data provenance window. However, when I try to click view or download there appears to be no response. The same happens when I attempt to view through the list queue of the connection. [Screenshot of the processor and its link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3pCc.png).

Would appreciate any advice on how to resolve this, thanks!

Comment: Right click on queue and you will get an option `List queue` ,  you will see a list of flowfiles under that queue, click on small information like icon and then  `View`  option to see flowfile content

Comment: Should have noted that I had already tried this. Going through the information window and clicking on view/download from there also gives no response. Do you have any other idea on why this is happening?

Comment: To troubleshoot, try to disable/stop `Wait`  processor and then list queue